# JavaScript работа со скриптами

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы все скрипты описанные в хэдере запускались по нажатию на кнопку , пробовал поместить их в функцию и вызывать функцию после нажатия , не получилось. Как решить этот вопрос ?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="libraries/p5.sound.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="node.js"></script>  
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="tree.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <p>Введите количество узлов</p>
        <input id="textbox" type="text" />
    </form>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var textboxValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox").value);       
    </script>

    <form>      
        <input id="button1" type="button" value="Кнопка" onclick="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Убрать их из head, и добавлять из js

```
var scripts = [
    "libraries/p5.js",
    "libraries/p5.dom.js",
    "libraries/p5.sound.js",
    "node.js",  
    "tree.js",
    "sketch.js"
];
function loadScripts() {
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = scripts[i];
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

.

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Кнопка" onclick="loadScripts" />
```